# Mongo: Query to get count of objects in a nested objects in array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql

I need to retrieve this data if I have items in funds,
or to retrieve fields with items count.

query :

```
db.getCollection('contact')
.aggregate([    {$match: {guid: “456”}},
        {$unwind: '$accounts'},
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'accounts',
                localField: 'accounts.id',
                foreignField: 'id',
                as: 'accounts_info'
            }
        },
        {$project: {'accounts_info.subAccounts.items': 1, 'contacts.Id': 1, fullName : 1}}
    ]) .toArray();
```

result:

```
[
 {
    "_id" : “234”,
    "accounts" : [ 
        {
            “subAccounts : {
                "items" : [ 
                   {
                        "isExitDataReady" : false,
                        "Name" : “aaaa”,
                        "exitDate" : null,
                        "date" : "2019-08-14T00:00:00+03:00",
                        "CreatedDate" : "2020-03-05T10:03:40.000+0000",
                        "Id" : “00000000”,
                  
                    }, 
                  {
                        "isExitDataReady" : false,
                        "Name" : “aaaa”,
                        "exitDate" : null,
                        "date" : "2019-08-14T00:00:00+03:00",
                        "CreatedDate" : "2020-03-05T10:03:40.000+0000",
                        "Id" : “00000000”,
                  
                    }, 
           {
                        "isExitDataReady" : false,
                        "Name" : “aaaa”,
                        "exitDate" : null,
                        "date" : "2019-08-14T00:00:00+03:00",
                        "CreatedDate" : "2020-03-05T10:03:40.000+0000",
                        "Id" : “00000000”,
                  
                    }, 
            {
                        "isExitDataReady" : false,
                        "Name" : “aaaa”,
                        "exitDate" : null,
                        "date" : "2019-08-14T00:00:00+03:00",
                        "CreatedDate" : "2020-03-05T10:03:40.000+0000",
                        "Id" : “00000000”,
                  
                    }, 
                     {
                        "isExitDataReady" : false,
                        "Name" : “aaaa”,
                        "exitDate" : null,
                        "date" : "2019-08-14T00:00:00+03:00",
                        "CreatedDate" : "2020-03-05T10:03:40.000+0000",
                        "Id" : “00000000”,
                  
                    }
    
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : “567,
    "subAccounts" : [ 
        {
            “funsd” : {
                "items" : [ 
                    {
                        "isExitDataReady" : false,
                        "Name" : “aaaa”,
                        "exitDate" : null,
                        "date" : "2019-08-14T00:00:00+03:00",
                        "CreatedDate" : "2020-03-05T10:03:40.000+0000",
                        "Id" : “00000000”,
                  
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
 }
]
```

I tried:

- To add on  `$match {'accounts_info.subAccounts.items': {$exist : true}}`
  But I did not get any data back at all.
- To add on  `$match {'accounts_info.subAccounts.items.itemId': {$gt : 0}}`
  But I did not get any data back at all.

Comment: The output you show is curious since neither `'accounts_info.subAccounts.items'`, nor `'contacts.Id'`, nor `"fullName"` appear in the output.

Comment: Sorry, I want to fix this, but I StackOverflow blocks me, I get this error: "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details".

Comment: Perhaps if you add some minimized/redacted sample documents of the `contact` and `accounts` collections, with the desired output, SO won't complain and readers will have a better idea of what you are looking for.

Comment: FYI, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156642/why-cant-i-post-this-to-stack-overflow-its-giving-me-an-error/156643#156643